# Using JavaScript to animate MathJax equation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mathjax

I would like to perform a seamless animation which gives the impression of substituting variables into an expression step by step. However there are a few issues that make it rather ugly.

1. When an element fadesOut the element below moves upward one position. How can I get the element to stay where it is?
2. Aesthetically it is a bit ugly. If anyone could guide me to resources to make it more elegant that would be great. Also if you have an idea to make it prettier using JS please give it a try!

```js
$('#next').hide();
$('#next2').hide();
$('#next3').hide();
$('#next4').hide();
$('#next5').hide();
$('#next6').hide();
$('#next7').hide();
$('#next8').hide();

$('#next').fadeIn(1000);
$('#start').fadeOut(1000);
$('#next4').fadeIn(3000);
$('#next').fadeOut(1000);
$('#next3').fadeIn(4000);
$('#next5').fadeIn(4000);
$('#next3').fadeOut(1000);
$('#next4').fadeOut(3000);
$('#next6').fadeIn(5000);
$('#next5').fadeOut(3000);
$('#next6').fadeOut(6000);
$('#next7').fadeIn(13000);
$('#next7').fadeOut(1000);
$('#next8').fadeIn(15000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_CHTML"></script>
<div id="equation">
  <h2 id="start">`KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \omega^2`</h2>
  <br>
  <h2 id="next">`\omega =sqrt(2\alpha \Delta degrees)`</h2>
  <br>
  <h2 id="next2">`KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I sqrt(2\alpha \Delta degrees)`</h2>
  <br>
  <h2 id="next3">`\alpha = frac\{tau_{max}} {I}`</h2>
  <br>
  <h2 id="next4">`KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \sqrt{(2 (\frac{\tau_{max}} {I})   \Delta degrees)}^2`</h2>
  <br>
  <h2 id="next5">`KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \(2 (\frac{\tau_{max}} {I}) \Delta degrees)`</h2>
  <br>
  <h2 id="next6">`KE_{rot} = \tau_{max}\Delta degrees`</h2>
  <br>
  <h2 id="next7">`\tau_{max} = I \alpha`</h2>
  <br>
  <h2 id="next8">`KE_{rot} = I \ \alpha \  \Delta   degrees`</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the `<h2>` in order?  I'm not following the flow of the animation.

Comment: yes the <h2> elements are in order but the Id's are not. I will fix that

Comment: Ok I change the order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ditch using `<h2>` and `<br>` tags.  Have a collection of `<div>` sets that will serve as slides.  Give each one the `slide` class.  Put which equations you want to display on each slide.  Do some fancy stuff with `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Promise`s to transition between slides.

```js
$(function() {
  // I have no idea why jQuery doesn't have a reduce function
  $.fn.reduce = Array.prototype.reduce;

  // Create a chain of promises
  function waterfall(arr, action) {
    arr.reduce(function(prev, next) {
      return prev.then(function() {
        return action(next);
      });
    }, Promise.resolve());
  }

  // Function to actual fade an element in/out and return a promise
  function fader(el) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $(el).fadeIn(2000).promise().done(function() {
        this.fadeOut(1000).promise().done(function() {
          resolve();
        });
      });
    });
  }

  // Bootstrap
  waterfall($(".slide"), fader);
});
```

```css
.math-set {
  text-align: center;
}
.slide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=AM_CHTML"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="math-set">
  <div class="slide">
    <div>`KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \omega^2`</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>`\omega =sqrt(2\alpha \Delta degrees)`</div>
    <div>`KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I sqrt(2\alpha \Delta degrees)`</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>`\alpha = frac\{tau_{max}} {I}`</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>`KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \sqrt{(2 (\frac{\tau_{max}} {I}) \Delta degrees)}^2`</div>
    <div>`KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \(2 (\frac{\tau_{max}} {I}) \Delta degrees)`</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>`KE_{rot} = \tau_{max}\Delta degrees`</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>`\tau_{max} = I \alpha`</div>
    <div>`KE_{rot} = I \ \alpha \ \Delta degrees`</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like this display! However I am going have to read up on the promise documentation. How could I edit it to display two <h2> during selected iterations?

Comment: @RyeGuy Do you mean during different animation key frames or having 2 h2 through the whole animation?

Comment: During different animation key frames

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `hide()` changes the display property to 'none'. The `fadeOut` does the same thing when it finishes. This causes the element to be removed from the layout entirely, causing the next one to shift upward.

There are a couple of approaches you could take to fix this. One would be to animate the opacity property directly instead of using the `fadeOut` shortcut. For example, `.animate({opacity: 0})`.

Another possible way of handling this, possibly more aesthetically pleasing, would be to create a wrapper div the height of one equation, then insert the equations into that div with `overflow: hidden` and animate the scroll position to show each equation in turn. (You would want to set the height of every equation div to be equal in that case.)

Comment: Brilliant idea! It would provide the flexibility I need to make some spicy animation. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of just cycling through the list and updating the html in place.  Not sure why my fades or math stuffs aren't working in the fiddle, but this should be a good start.

```
<div id="equation">
  <h2 id="start"></h2>
</div>


var strings = [
    `KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \omega^2`,
  `\omega =sqrt(2\alpha \Delta degrees)`,
  `KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I sqrt(2\alpha \Delta degrees)`,
  `\alpha = frac\{tau_{max}} {I}`,
  `KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \sqrt{(2 (\frac{\tau_{max}} {I}) \Delta degrees)}^2`,
  `KE_{rot} = \frac1 2 I \(2 (\frac{\tau_{max}} {I}) \Delta degrees)`,
  `KE_{rot} = \tau_{max}\Delta degrees`,
  `\tau_{max} = I \alpha`,
  `KE_{rot} = I \ \alpha \  \Delta   degrees`
];

var i = 0;

var eq = function(){
    if(i <= strings.length) {
    $('#equation > h2').html(strings[i]);
    i++;  
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

var interval = setInterval(eq, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adjavaherian/6yg28as4/